# Travelling Through Selections While Using CountA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through my worksheet, and count if a few different ranges have anything in them. At the moment I cannot figure out how to change the ranges in the CountA function without using .Select, which a large portion of the VBA community does not like to use so I try my best to stay away from it.

```
Dim BoxCounter As Integer
Dim TestCounter As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim TestExists As Integer
i=0
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Configuration Sheets")
    While (BoxCounter <= 571) 'goes to the last row used for this specific sheet. 

            If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(("F" & (4 + i * 25) & ":F" & (15 + i * 25))) >= 1) Then
            TestExists = TestExists + 1
            i = i + 1
            BoxCounter = BoxCounter + 30 'adds on so that I can loop through all of the rows, 30 is the size of the specific information spaces
        Wend
    End With
```

Comment: Is this code not working ? or what's the error ?

Comment: The code was not working because I did not understand how to use CountA in VBA with a variable. Everyone else that has posted examples online have had exact ranges that they wanted to check for. I ended up shedding this idea completely and just did a nested loop that checks every cell individually, then jumps to the next section that I want to check, which is not as efficient but still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA("range")`, `"range"` will refer to active worksheet, unless you use `"worksheet!range"` format. So, instead of using string range, better to use range object from desired worksheet:

```
Dim BoxCounter As Integer
Dim TestCounter As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim TestExists As Integer
i=0
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Configuration Sheets")
    While (BoxCounter <= 571) 'goes to the last row used for this specific sheet. 

            If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("F" & (4 + i * 25) & ":F" & (15 + i * 25))) >= 1) Then
            TestExists = TestExists + 1
            i = i + 1
            BoxCounter = BoxCounter + 30 'adds on so that I can loop through all of the rows, 30 is the size of the specific information spaces
        Wend
    End With
```